# "Pass" function call from class to class, C++

Tags: c++, class, call

Is there a way to pass a function call from class to class?
For example:

```
//foo.cpp
foo::foo
{
  ...
  myfoo2 = new foo2();
  ...
}

//foo2.h
class foo2
{
  ...
  public:
  void method1();
  void method2(int arg2)
  ...
}
```

Now I want to use the method of foo2 (eg method2) from outside of the foo class
without having to implement the following:

```
//foo.cpp
...
void foo::method2(int arg2)
{
  myfoo2->method2(arg2);
}
```

The problem is, that i have quite a lot of these, and this would take a lot of space and does not look nice.
Is there any other solution, or at lest a short version with the same effect?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about `myfoo.myfoo2->method2(...)` (or `myfoo->myfoo2->method2(...)`)

Comment: Mb in your case it will be better use Inheritance instead of incapsulation? 

Or just some method like `foo2 * getFoo2() { return myfoo2; }`, and then use something like `myfoo1.getFoo2()->method2(param)` ??

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to achieve. Why does one have to go through `foo` and cannot simply get a `foo2` to call its methods?

Comment: I am using Qt and my design relies on signals and slots. Therefore i can not use a pointer since from the outside of the class it should look like a slot. Also i can not inherit in a conventional since multiple inheritances of QObject are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use private inheritance to include a foo2 object in your foo class, without creating an is-a relationship. Then you can simply expose the function with a using statement, like so:

```
class foo : private foo2
{
public:
    using foo2::method2;
};
```

Comment: This sounded like a great solution to me, but unfortunately in my case, i am working with Qt and both classes (foo and foo2) inherit from QObject. Multiple inheritances from QObjects are not allowed.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Private inheritance is essentially the same as aggregation except you don't give the member a name. What happens if you try it?

Comment: absolutely, without it, it compiles fine. As soon as I add it, i get plenty of 'Object' is an ambiguous base of 'foo' where i try to connect signals and slots between foo and some other class. When i comment the section with the errors out, it just shifts the error to another place, does not seem to be connected to the actual connection. Any ideas?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first

Answer (score 1):

If `foo` is just a handle or wrapper for a `foo2` it might make sense to overload `operator->`:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo2 {
public:
  void method1(){ std::cout << "method1\n"; }
  void method2(int /*arg2*/) { std::cout << "method2\n"; }
};

class foo {
  foo2 myfoo2;
public:
  foo2* operator->() { return &myfoo2; }
};

int main() {
  foo f;
  f->method1();
  f->method2(1);
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SdsQ4Zh5wnEQ75yM).

Answer (score 0):

Why not have one method in your foo class that returns a pointer (or const pointer) to your foo2 class like so:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo2* getFoo2() const { return foo2_; }

private:
    foo2* foo2_;
};
```

Then on the outside you can use it like so:

```
foo f;
auto f2 = f.getFoo2();
f2->method1();
f2->method2(/*args*/);
```